# How to use multiple CTS media files when running test modules on Android Test Station

Tags: android, android-testing, cts

I am running CTS tests on Android Test Station and am facing an issue. It is regarding these three test cases:

- CtsMediaTestCases
- CtsMediaStressTestCases
- CtsMediaBitstreamsTestCases

All three of them require media files that are available on the official Android website. However, since Android 12, the first one is using 1.5 version of the files, while the other two are using 1.4 . The problem is that on the Android Test Station, I don't have option to choose multiple files.

If I put only one of them, the other one is causing problems. Did anyone encounter the same problem and knows how to solve it? It is important to me to not split it into multiple runs, but to have one run for all modules.